# Counting log instances in the last year in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring

I need to obtain the sum of log instances in GCP over the entire year. Because I have multiple GCP Projects I have created Log Sinks to send all the logs I want to count to the same project.

I then created a log-based metric of type Counter that counts the log instances. I now need to create an alert that triggers when the number of these log instances exceeds a certain threshold.

My issue is that the logs are stored for only 7 days in GCP, but I need to have the total count continue to increase even after those 7 days as the threshold could be triggered after 3 months. How can I save the highest count and only add to it when other instances of the log appear?

Comment: Open [Google Sheets](https://sheets.google.com), and copy/paste the value in there.... ?

Comment: I am trying to create an alert in GCP so it will alert me when it exceeds the threshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue:

1. Created log sinks from all projects to send the specific logs to one of the projects(lets call it Project 1)
2. Created a log sink in Project 1 that send all those specific logs to a BigQuery dataset
3. Create a google cloud function that queries the BigQuery dataset and does a count and prints a log entry like: "Count: value".
4. Created a cloud scheduler job that triggers that function once an hour
5. Created a log-based metric of type distribution that gets the value from the log entries generated by the function
6. Created an alert that uses the log-based metric

I will leave below the details of each:

**Cloud function:**

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from flask import escape

def entry_point(request):
    # Set your GCP project ID
    project_id = "project_id"
    # Set your BigQuery dataset ID and table ID
    dataset_id = "dataset_id"
    table_id = "table_*"

    # Initialize BigQuery client
    client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)

    # Construct the SQL query
    query = f"SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM `{project_id}.{dataset_id}.{table_id}`"

    # Run the query
    query_job = client.query(query)

    # Get the count from the result
    count = query_job.result()
    for row in count:
        count_result = row['count']
    print('Count: '  + str(count_result))
    
    # Return the count as the response
    return f"Count: {count_result}"
```

**Cloud Scheduler:**

- Set the frequency as needed (in my case, once per hour "0 * * * *")
- Target type: "HTTP"
- URL: use the url from the "TRIGGER" page in the defined cloud function
- HTTP method: "GET"
- Auth header: "Add OIDC token"
- Service account: use a service account that you give in IAM the permission for "Cloud Functions Invoker"
- Audience: use the same url from above

**Log-based metric:**

- Metric Type: "Distribution"
- Select log scope: "Project logs"
- Build filter: "Count:"
- Field name: "textPayload"
- Regular expresion: ":(.*)$"

**Alert:**

```
fetch cloud_function
| metric 'logging.googleapis.com/user/log-based-metric-name'
      | align delta()
      | group_by 10m, [value_Collector_mean: mean(value.log-based-metric-nam)]
| condition val() > 100000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try these strategies to capture the year-long log counts for alerting:

1. You may consider extending your log retention for the relevant logs to a year-long in the [Log Router settings](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview). However it may incur some storage costs.
2. You may consider exporting logs to persistent storage. You can Log Sinks in your Cloud Storage to export logs for longer retention. You can setup Log Sinks to export logs to Big Query for analysis and querying.
3. Create a custom metric in Cloud Monitoring for the aggregated log counts for storing then create an alerting policy based on the custom metric that can be triggered once the threshold exceeds.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I created a log storage that stores for 1 year the logs, but my issue is that if I want to see the total number of logs. But when I use a MQL query such as:
fetch k8s_container
| metric 'logging.googleapis.com/user/LOG-METRIC'
    | align delta()
    | group_by 21h, [value_sum: sum(value.METRIC)]
    | group_by [resource.project_id]
I cant group them for more than one day. And so even if I have all the logs from one year, the sum of them all is dependent of the group_by expresion and I can't use group_by 365d for example